# Screenshot of maps created by Mapbox and used it in a research paper: is it legal?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I created a website containing a map using the mapbox-GL-JS library. Now I hope to make a screenshot of it and used it in my research paper. But I am not sure whether it is legal? I cannot find detailed information on MapBox's homepage.

Can you help me? Thank you!